# sql server function to mysql with same logic

Tags: mysql

The below sql server function is converted to mysql but in mysql the substring is working in different manner when compared to sql server 
can anyone make this execute in mysql with same logic?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Num_ToWords] (

@Number Numeric (38, 0) -- Input number with as many as 18 digits

) RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) 


AS BEGIN

   DECLARE @inputNumber VARCHAR(38)
 DECLARE @NumbersTable TABLE (number CHAR(2), word VARCHAR(10))
  DECLARE @outputString VARCHAR(8000)
 DECLARE @length INT
 DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @loops INT
 DECLARE @position INT
DECLARE @chunk CHAR(3) -- for chunks of 3 numbers
DECLARE @tensones CHAR(2)
DECLARE @hundreds CHAR(1)
DECLARE @tens CHAR(1)
DECLARE @ones CHAR(1)

IF @Number = 0 Return 'Zero'

-- initialize the variables
SELECT @inputNumber = CONVERT(varchar(38), @Number)
 , @outputString = ''
 , @counter = 1
SELECT @length   = LEN(@inputNumber)
 , @position = LEN(@inputNumber) - 2
 , @loops    = LEN(@inputNumber)/3

-- make sure there is an extra loop added for the remaining numbers
IF LEN(@inputNumber) % 3 <> 0 SET @loops = @loops + 1

 -- insert data for the numbers and words
 INSERT INTO @NumbersTable   SELECT '00', ''
UNION ALL SELECT '01', 'one' UNION ALL SELECT '02', 'two'
UNION ALL SELECT '03', 'three' UNION ALL SELECT '04', 'four'
UNION ALL SELECT '05', 'five'  UNION ALL SELECT '06', 'six'
UNION ALL SELECT '07', 'seven' UNION ALL SELECT '08', 'eight'
UNION ALL SELECT '09', 'nine'  UNION ALL SELECT '10', 'ten'
UNION ALL SELECT '11', 'eleven'UNION ALL SELECT '12', 'twelve'
UNION ALL SELECT '13', 'thirteen'UNION ALL SELECT '14', 'fourteen'
UNION ALL SELECT '15', 'fifteen' UNION ALL SELECT '16', 'sixteen'
UNION ALL SELECT '17', 'seventeen'UNION ALL SELECT '18', 'eighteen'
UNION ALL SELECT '19', 'nineteen'UNION ALL SELECT '20', 'twenty'
UNION ALL SELECT '30', 'thirty'  UNION ALL SELECT '40', 'forty'
UNION ALL SELECT '50', 'fifty'   UNION ALL SELECT '60', 'sixty'
UNION ALL SELECT '70', 'seventy' UNION ALL SELECT '80', 'eighty'
UNION ALL SELECT '90', 'ninety'   

WHILE @counter <= @loops BEGIN

-- get chunks of 3 numbers at a time, padded with leading zeros
SET @chunk = RIGHT('000' + SUBSTRING(@inputNumber, @position, 3), 3)

IF @chunk <> '000' BEGIN
    SELECT @tensones = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 2, 2)
         , @hundreds = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 1, 1)
         , @tens = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 2, 1)
         , @ones = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 3, 1)

    -- If twenty or less, use the word directly from @NumbersTable
    IF CONVERT(INT, @tensones) <= 20 OR @Ones='0' BEGIN
        SET @outputString = (SELECT word 
                                  FROM @NumbersTable 
                                  WHERE @tensones = number)
               + CASE @counter WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                   WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                   WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                   WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                   WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                   WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                   WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '  WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                   ELSE '' END
                           + @outputString
        END
     ELSE BEGIN -- break down the ones and the tens separately

         SET @outputString = ' ' 
                        + (SELECT word 
                                FROM @NumbersTable 
                                WHERE @tens + '0' = number)
                         + '-'
                         + (SELECT word 
                                FROM @NumbersTable 
                                WHERE '0'+ @ones = number)
               + CASE @counter WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                   WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                   WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                   WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                   WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                   WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                   WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '   WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                   ELSE '' END
                        + @outputString
    END

    -- now get the hundreds
    IF @hundreds <> '0' BEGIN
        SET @outputString  = (SELECT word 
                                  FROM @NumbersTable 
                                  WHERE '0' + @hundreds = number)
                            + ' hundred ' 
                            + @outputString
    END
END

SELECT @counter = @counter + 1
     , @position = @position - 3

   END

   -- Remove any double spaces
   SET @outputString = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@outputString, '  ', ' ')))
   SET @outputstring = UPPER(LEFT(@outputstring, 1)) +
    SUBSTRING(@outputstring, 2,    8000)


    RETURN @outputString -- return the result
   END
```

Comment: Could you describe what the differences are?

Comment: Here Substring works differently, if the position value is negative.

Comment: . . And MySQL substring can also only take two arguments.  I know what the differences are in the functions.

Comment: Please check the code in sql server and my sql. For example in sql server the query SELECT SUBSTRING('Haieverybody',-1,5) produces "hai" as o/p and the same produces "y" in mysql. so this causes the difference in the o/p with the above mentioned function.